# Is it possible to find the minimal polynomial of a matrix knowing its rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, minimal-polynomials

We know that any $n \times n$ matrix $X$ with $rank(X)=1$ can be written $u(^Tv)$ where $u, v$ are vectors and $^TA$ is the transpose of $A$. This leads to $X^2=u(^Tv)u(^Tv)=u(^Tvu)(^Tv)=cu(^Tv)$, where $c$ is the scalar product of $u$ and $v$. We can see that $tr(X)=tr(u(^Tv))=tr((^Tv)u)=c$. Thus $X^2=tr(X)X$. This looks very similar to the characteristic polynomial of a $2\times2$ matrix, with the determinant $0$. Is $x^2-tr(X)x$ the minimal polynomial for an arbirary matrix with $rank(X)=1$? And can we generalize this for $rank(X)=k < n$? It seems intuitive that if $rank(X)=2$ then $X^3-tr(X)X^2+\frac{tr(X)^2-tr(X^2)}{2}X$ is $0$. Can this be generalized?

Comment: There are many matrices with the same rank but a different minimal polynomial... Just take diagonal matrices with different coefficients on the diagonal (and no $0$ so that they all have rank $n$).

Comment: In the example I gave above the minimal polynomial depends on the matrix itself. If $rank(X)=1$ then $X^2-tr(X)X=0$. And I think that this is also the minimal polynomial.

Comment: A good starting place would be the fact that in general (in characteristic $0$) the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is expressible in terms of traces of powers of $A$: see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#:~:text=In%20linear%20algebra%2C%20the%20characteristic,the%20matrix%20among%20its%20coefficients.

Comment: The rank only gives some information about a possible eigenvalue $0$, so in general it will not help a lot to find the minimal polynomial. For instance even if in addition it is given that the characteristic polynomial is $(X-1)^n$, then the minimal polynomial will be some $(X-1)^k$, but the rank is always $n$ and of no help in determining which $k$ to take. Only if the rank is quite small (like $1$) does it give a lot of information, because it implies a high (geometric) multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$.